# Image texture not covering the whole sphere

Tags: texturing, objects

[image]My son is just starting to learn how to use Blender.  He is trying to put an image texture on a sphere, which is an assignment for class.  When he puts it in as image texture for the base color it puts it on but not over the whole sphere.  I am attaching a picture here.  It works fine on his computer at school but not our computer at home running Windows 10 with 32GB of memory and all Windows and hardware drivers up to date.

[image]

When I went through the Shader editor this was the result:[image]

Comment: hello, it's hard to say why it doesn't work as we don't know how you've tried to project the texture on the sphere, please also show the Shader Editor and the UV Editor

Comment: He added a mesh uv sphere, changed the shade to smooth, and then in material properties he added a new property and clicked on the yellow dot next to base color, chose image texture and pointed to his marble.png image.  How do we get into the Shader and UV Editor?

Comment: At the top of the Blender window there is a series of tabs with names in them.  Click on the tab with "Shading" in the title to get to the shader editor easily.  This sounds like a version difference issue.  Do you know what version of Blender he's using?  It should say in the startup splash screen.

Comment: He is using 3.0.1.  I added a Shading screen shot.

Comment: Hi :). You can also share the Blend file through https://pasteall.org/blend/, so others can take a look ;)

Answer (score 2):

To quickly texture your sphere, open the *Shader Editor*, then create this chain of nodes (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to create a node): *(Input) Texture Coordinate* (use its *Object* output) > *(Vector) Mapping > (Texture) Image Texture* (load your marble image, switch it from *Flat* to *Box*, increase the *Blend* value) > *(Shader) Principled BSDF* > *(Output) Material Output*:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an UV issue to me, try going into Edit Mode on the Sphere, pressing U, and choosing Sphere Projection

Comment: That didn't work either, just got a different result.  Now the marble is a flat disk in the center of the sphere.